SPL-TOKEN with token extensions enabled specifically transfer hooks ... would the SPL-BURN instruction invoke the transfer hook?
Follow on question from my earlier (and first) question regarding SPL-BURN instruction...
If I have an SPL-TOKEN with token extentions enabled, specifically the transfer hooks extension ... if a user invoked the SPL-BURN instruction to BURN a token, would the SPL-BURN instruction invoke my transfer hook custom program logic before executing the BURN or would the BURN be able to bypass the transfer hook?
GZERO - Recycle LABS

Quick follow-up ... any help on this question?
Does a SPL-Token Extension 'Transfer hook' enabled TOKEN trigger the transfer hook call if the user tries to burn it?
I have read with the Non-transferable TE function a user can still burn a token - however there is no docs on the Transfer Hook : Burn function interaction.

The transfer hook only calls during transfers, and not burns or mints.
